# Particles.js doesn't continue when I scroll down the page- HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles, particles.js

So, I made a page in a website, and I used Particles.js for the background.
Now, when I scroll down, the particles don't continue down, they stop at the initial corner of the screen, they don't go down if I scroll...
these are my particles' settings:

```
#particles {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: -1;
background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50% ;background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

Here's a pic of the website, as you can see, the white space at the bottom of the page is always like that, the particles don't go there they just bounce back.
How can I remove the limit for the size of the website for particles?
Thanks!

[image: Website]

Comment: try to add  `overflow-y: scroll;`

Comment: you have to use **overflow: hidden** I think its useful for you

Comment: Sorry, none of those suggestions worked...

Answer (score 3):

you have written position :absolute ; replace it with position :fixed;